# Java Reflection: getting the type of the return parameter of a method

Tags: java, reflection, instantiation, invocationtargetexception

Yes, I know there are plenty of articles on the topic, but it's not that simple.

I've got a wrapper class which is used for generically passing arguments to methods and subsequently retrieving values. This wrapper class (called `IDVariant`) has a default type which indicates the principal type of variable stored.

Hence, I can have:

```
IDVariant v = new IDVariant(1);
boolean b = v.booleanValue();
String s = v.stringValue();
int i = v.integerValue();
```

and so on, but the default type would be `int`, as per the type of the parameter used to create the instance.

Now, this class, as mentioned, is used as a general placeholder in much bigger and more complex classes. I need to create a tool which parses a super-structure of classes recursively and recreate this structure in XML. Obviously, the way to go is Reflection, and I have been successful so far in recreating the structure of the whole thing. The only problem is, I have not come up with a way to find out the default type of the IDVariant, and thus having the correct type for each variable of the XML tree.

What I have tried doing is retrieving the `get` method for each property of each class, then invoking it and checking the default type of each IDVariant. It seemed like a good idea, but it's not working: I am getting an `InvocationTargetException` which, I presume, is due to the fact that the instance of the class I create in order to call the method, is in fact not populated with data. It's the only logical explanation I have been able to give.

If anyone has any idea, I would be most appreciative! :)

Following is a sample code fragment:

```
// Edit of the code, as correctly indicated by cyon. Tha variable className is given.
Class<?> toParse = Class.forName(className);
Object o = toParse.newInstance();   // There is a default constructor with no values, the object is not null

Class cl = ... // given class
Class[] noparams = {};

String s = "getSomeValue";
Method method = null;
for(Method m : cl.getMethods()) {
    if (m.getName().equals(s)) {
        method = m;
        break;
    }
}

if (method != null) {
    try {
        Object idv = method.invoke(o, noparams);  // exception occurs at this point
        String type = decodeType((IDVariant)idv); // function which maps internal codes of IDVariant default type to primitive and internal types
        return type;
    } catch (InvocationTargetException ex) {
        System.out.println(ex.getCause());
    }
}
```

NOTE: The function returns indeed a variable of type IDVariant, I have checked the source code out. I cannot change that code, however, as it is coming from an external tool which generates it automatically.

Thank you in advance :)

EDIT: Okay, so I've had a better look at the source produced by the external tool, and this is what I gather:

I am invoking a sample method, say `getSomeValue`. In the source of the class where the method is declared, here is the declaration of the method:

```
public IDVariant getSomeValue() { return GetPropDirect(externalValue); }
```

So, perhaps it's internally trying to invoke another method which belongs to a superclass, and I do not instantiate the superclass. Is it possible that this is the issue? And if yes, is there a workaround?

EDIT 2: As requested, here is the Stack Trace for the exception I am getting:

```
java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at prove.Reflector.getImplicitType(Reflector.java:275)
    at prove.Reflector.recurr(Reflector.java:134)
    at prove.Reflector.ParseToXml(Reflector.java:69)
    at prove.Main.main(Main.java:12)
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
    at com.progamma.doc.IDDocument.GetPropDirect(IDDocument.java:739)
    at it.zerounoesse.Calcolo7302013.Contribuente.getSomeValue(Contribuente.java:70)
... 8 more
```

Comment: So what is in the variable `o`? If the `getSomeValue` is throwing an exception chances are high it is because of what is in `o`.

Comment: You are correct, I forgot to add the definition for `o`. I have edited the code to indicate this. However, when debugging, I can see that the object `o` is instantiated, it has all the values it should, anthough most of them are null. Should I invoke the default `Constructor` directly instead of using the method I'm currently using? Thank you for your time... :)

Comment: As the return type is not part of the method signature. I don't know if what you ask is possible.

Comment: What's under the InvocationTargetException? What's the underlying exception? Post the stack trace.

Comment: Arnaud, I think you are right. I have changed my approach and used another property, directly available through a dynamically created instance. It seems like the codes I need to determine the basic type of the `IDVariant` are indeed present somewhere else. I have, however, included the stack trace as asked by EJP.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your `IDVariant` class is of course instantiated, thats what you do with `toParse.newInstance()` method, but since you do not cast the instantiated object to its original class type and then initialize it, there is a big probability of exception, for example NullPointerEx.

Comment: What does this mean? A constructed object is already initialised. No amount of casting is going to change that.

Comment: Not in this case, askers `IDVariant v = new IDVariant(1);` takes value in the constructor, so if empty constructor is called, class fields are nulls => calling class methods may result in NPEs. Thats why field initilization needs to be done through setters(casting needed) or through `Constructor` reflection.

Comment: Yes, I think AWB is right. Your post made me search an alternative, and it seems I have found something. If it works, I will post it here for future reference.

Comment: I was not able to resolve the problem initially described, however I did manage to find a workaround based on the implementation of the automated code. I am accepting awb's answer as correct as it seems to be the most logical explanation. Thanks again for your time :)

Comment: Your explanation doesn't explain your strange wording. He's calling the wrong constructor, or not *further* initializing the object. It has nothing to do with casting.